# pass objects in WPF XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am new to coding GUI stuff, and I was wondering if anyone could tell me whether there is a way to pass objects in xaml to the constructor of another FrameworkElement.

Right now, I am using the code-behind to send an object that does not derive from any of the allowed types in XAML. However, If I were to make the class being passed derive from frameworkElement as well, would it be possible to pass it as an object to a constructor or perhaps set a field to it?

for example

or can properties only be normal value types and is there no way to use constructors beside the default one?

As I said I am currently just passing stuff to the constructor in the C# file that goes with the xaml, but I feel like it would be convenient if it were possible to pass with xaml.

Comment: Can you provide any code?

Answer (score 1):

Your doing it wrong.

Unless you are writing a real "user control" There should be very little logic in your view code behind or view constructor.  Instead almost all of the logic should be in either View Model or Model types that get into your view through data binding.

This of course isn't always 100% possible, in which case the 'Field' you are looking for is called DataContext.  You can set this to an object and then subscribe to the `DataContextChanged` event and do whatever view specific logic you need there.

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx among others for more.

Comment: I am still too confused. I hate to bother you, but I really want to understand how to obey MVVM principles. I have tried reading a lot, but I don't think I'm grasping the most fundamental part of what I'm doing wrong. I am trying to implement a new user control, and I have data stored in an list<signals>

I want to hit a load button and have it load a user control into the grid. The user control needs a signal from the list in order to know what to display. How do I avoid passing it in the constructor? Or is it ok, since I am actually making a custom control?

Comment: did some more reading on data context. Is the gist of the idea that I need to 
1. Make a data context of the parent object and set a field to the list<signals> 
2. Reference the List<Signals> somewhere in the C# or XAML of the other object.

Comment: Still not really enough details to help you well.  Based on what I think you are asking you probably want an `IObservable` instead of a list, which you will bind to an items control in the parent object and use a `DataTemplate` or `DataTemplateSector` to materialize controls for each item in the collection.  If you need to pass in the collection to the child you can also look at declaring a `DependencyProperty` on the child control and binding the collection to that.

Comment: thanks, I think you are answering what I asked. Also your sentences will help my google searching a lot. Greatly appreciated.

I think the latter is what I am looking for probably. After reading several articles on data binding, I think I understand what I should have done. I'm pretty sure everyone was answering my question to begin with, but i didn't really understand it earlier. So many terms getting thrown all over the place. Thanks again